# numactl --localalloc on Mysql

Tags: mysql, memory, intel, numa, numactl

I run mysql on 2*Intel 6226 Server.

When I use `numactl -N 0 --localalloc /usr/sbin/mysqld` to start mysql service I find that the memory from node 1 is be used, which is different from using option `numactl -N 0 -m 0 /usr/sbin/mysqld`.

Why `numactl --localalloc` can’t Limit memory usage to node 0 ?

Please help explain why this happens.

Much thanks！

[Node memory when using numactl -N 0 -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAVYf.png)

[Node memory when using numactl -N 0 -m 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYHoq.png)

[Mysql execute command in /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orm1p.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/numactl/numactl/issues/143

--localalloc ：Preferably allocate memory on local node, but if memory cannot be allocated there fall back to other nodes, like --preferred local node, it is kernel default mempolicy.

so `numactl -N 0 --localalloc` is more like `numactl -N 0 --preferred 0`;

but `numactl -N 0 -m 0` mean only allocate memory from nodes, Allocation will fail when there is not enough memory available on nodes.